# Indexes in Teradata

Tags: teradata

How to Enable/Disable Indexes in TERADATA Database?

I want to disable indexes and do update and then enable the indexes in Teradata.

If Enable/Disable option not available in Teradata, in the sense How can I achieve this ? If I use DROP Indexes, how can I recreate the indexes for all the tables?

Comment: There's no deferred update to an index in Teradata. To recreate an index you simply run `CREATE INDEX` again. But why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: No, Actually I'm working under data masking, so for that I have to do disable/enable the indexes on scramble. So do you have any solution?

Comment: If *data masking* means *update all data in a column to a new value* you better create a new table and Insert/Select, this will be magnitudes faster (and never do that on the PI). Otherwise the solution is DROP INDEX & CREATE INDEX

Answer (score 3):

Teradata gives you a way to create a table without choosing for primary index (if you are sure of any column).

You can create table with No primary Index. Here is a sample of how to do so:

```
Create table <table name> 
(<columnname> <datatype>,
<columnname> <datatype>) 
no primary index ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Teradata does not have a disable index feature.

All tables have a Primary Index (PI) which is chosen by the RDBMS unless you specify one.

```
CREATE INDEX <index name> (<column list>) ON table name;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX (department) ON tbl_employee;

DROP INDEX ind_dept ON tbl_employee;

DROP INDEX (department,emp_number) ON tbl_employee;
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Teradata` you can't drop `Primary index of a table`. The `primary index` defines where data will reside and which AMP receives the row.

To alter the `primary index` of a table you need to `delete all` the records from the table **`( As data is already distributed by the row hash value of the PI)`** then only you can change the primary index of a table by using below command:-

```
Alter table table_name modify primary index index_name (column list);
```

Steps to achieve your goal

- You can crate a new table with your desired index **`( temp, wrk, intermediate table)`** insert the records from the original table and update the wrk table.
- delete the original table and insert the wrk table data.

And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - you can't disable and re-enable indexes in Teradata.
However, there some workarounds.

**Drop Index**
If you talking about PI (primary index) - you can't drop it. All you can do is to make a copy of a table without an index.
You can drop secondary index though. Then simply create it again when you need it.

**Drop-Create Table**
This doesn't fit all cases, but often this is the fastest way to do the work, especially if the issue you have is with PI.

BTW: it is not clear, why would you need to do that? Performance or logic or something else? That probably will affect recommendation.

Comment: *Keep in mind, that in Teradata every index is basically a copy of original table spread differently across AMPs.* Huhh?

Comment: Sorry, but that's totally wrong. Tables in Teradata are spread across AMPs based on the defined Primary Index (similar to Hash-Partitioning). When you create a Secondary Index only the indexed columns plus the ROWID of the original row is stored on disk (in a kind of BTree similar to other DBMSes), on the same AMP for NUSIs and distributed by the indexed columns for USIs. Creating a copy of the table would be quite stupid (of course you could do it when you create a Join Index based on `SELECT *`).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Quote from documentation: "The system builds subtables for all SIs. The subtable contains the index rows that associate the SI value with one or more rows in the base table."

Answer (score 0):

Create & Drop index is the only option you have here

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify what kind of index you want to disable/enable, below are the approach you can follow on either cases.

- PRIMARY INDEX

  1. CREATE a new table with the same PI
  2. INSERT the **updated data** to new table
  3. DROP the old table - `DROP TABLE <OldTable>;`
  4. RENAME the new table same as the old one. - `RENAME TABLE <NewTable> TO <OldTable>;`

Above recommendation for Primary Index is only applicable if you are going to update a primary index column value. **If you will update other columns (not the PI column) then you can just issue an UPDATE Statement directly.**

- SECONDARY INDEX

  1. DROP the SI - `DROP INDEX <IndexName> ON <TableName>;`
  2. UPDATE table data
  3. RECREATE the SI - `CREATE INDEX <IndexName> (<ColumnList>) ON <TableName>;`